How to forward more that one port traffic from HTTP to HTTPS using nginx
I have a software which has multiple services, the UI of this software is running on port 3000 and the I have another service running on port 7547. I want a solution that redirects the incoming traffic. So when the server receives http://my-domain.com:7547 I want it to be forwarded to https://my-domain.com:7547, and when the server receives http://my-domain.com:3000 or https://my-domain.com:3000 to forward it to https://my-domain.com
How can i configure that?

This doesn't make any sense. And you can't run both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port, they need to be bound to separate ports.

What if i added different locations? for example, for 3000 i use /ui and for 7547 i use /?

You can proxy different locations on nginx to different target ports, yes. But that's not remotely what you are describing in your question.

What do you suggest if i want to achieve the goal in my original question? i'm sorry i'm new to this so i don't fully get it

My point is, it's completely unclear what your question is. Because what you are describing doesn't make any sense.

This question is similar to: How can I forward requests from my web server?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I edited the question, is it clear now?
